# Error when trying to capture some frames from a video using open cv (on windows / anaconda-pycharm)

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, pycharm, anaconda

I am working on an image processing project for which I need to capture some frames from a video. I am using this piece of codes to do it:

```
cap= cv.VideoCapture('directory')
if (cap.isOpened()== False):
    print("Error opening video stream or file")
else:
    ret2, frame2 = cap.read()
    cv.imwrite('Moment1.jpg', frame2)
```

I am struggling with these errors and I can not find a solution on the internet for windows and anaconda:

```
[ WARN:0@0.966] global C:\ci\opencv-suite_1656607030790\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2386) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin
[ WARN:0@0.966] global C:\ci\opencv-suite_1656607030790\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (2402) cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module uridecodebin0 reported: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
[ WARN:0@0.966] global C:\ci\opencv-suite_1656607030790\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.966] global C:\ci\opencv-suite_1656607030790\work\modules\videoio\src\cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

So, how can I overcome these errors?

Answer (score 1):

It has an easy solution. The plugins can be installed using this anaconda command:

```
conda install gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gstreamer
```

There were a conflict error with my environment. I managed to solve this error by creating a new environment, and starting with the gstreamer package/plugins, I installed all the required packages with working versions of them.